# Sort a python dictionary by key and return a dictionary instead of a list

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I would like some help with sorting a dictionary by the keys in the dictionary and return it as a dictionary, and not return it as a list.

Any help would be great!

Comment: A Python dictionary is unordered (it's a hash map), so you would have to use a different data type if you want to return it in some particular order (e.g. `collections.OrderedDict`).

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  Why do you need the dictionary in a particular order, and why doesn't a list of (key, value) pairs work for you?

Comment: What I would like to achieve is the following:  
  
    `{1:['1', '2', '3'], 4: ['5', '6', '7'], 2: ['10', '11']}`  
  
to this:  
  
    `{1:['1', '2', '3'], 2: ['10', '11'], 4: ['5', '6', '7']}`

Comment: Which, as I explained above, doesn't make any sense, since the items in a dictionary don't have a defined order.  That's why I'm asking what you are trying to achieve (and no, you are not trying to sort a dictionary, since this isn't a goal in itself).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an ordered dict as suggested in the comment, which will return the ordering of items as they are input into the dictionary.

But, if you really need to take an unsorted dict and convert it to an ordered dict: (assuming this is sorted by key)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_dict = {1:['1', '2', '3'], 4: ['5', '6', '7'], 2: ['10', '11']}

new_dict = OrderedDict((k, v) for k, v in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily verbose.  Simply `OrderedDict(sorted(myd_dict.items()))` does the trick.  (No need to edit though, since an identical answer already exists in the duplicate linked above.)